# Microsoft Deployment Toolkit Image Capture Removes Internet (NIC) Adapter Driver

Tags: deployment, microsoft

I am running Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) on Windows Server 2016. I am trying to capture a Windows 10 v1809 reference image from a Lenovo M710q NUC.

I edited the unattend answer xml file and added the following attributes to generalize and set them to true, as seen [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2153919-mdt-image-capture-fails-because-at-sysprep-network-card-is-removed) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/maintain-driver-configurations-when-capturing-a-windows-image), to both Windows10x64 and Windows10:

Microsoft-Windows-PnpSysprep/PersistAllDeviceInstalls PnpSysprep/DoNotCleanUpNonPresentDevices

The capture reference is made for Windows 1809 as well. I then updated the DeploymentShare folder from the MDT console.

During Sysprep, it removes the ethernet driver, amongst many others, and the machine gets disconnected from the network, terminating the capture. Windows reboots and finds the drivers itself, then after restarting the litetouch.wsf script, it repeats the same loop.

I have all the appropriate drivers in the Out-Of-Box Packages firectory in the MDT console. I checked the Drivers folder in the DeploymentShare directory and it didn't look like it imported the drivers like I did in the MDT.